# SaaS system with dynamic data model in production

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, database, nosql

I want to design a product which allows customers to create their own websites. A customer will be able to maintain his website's data model on the fly, do queries on it and display the output on a html page. I doubt a traditional RDMBS is the right choice for two reasons; with every customer the amount of data will grow and the RDBMS might reach its limits even if scaled. As the data model is highly dynamic doing many DDL queries will slow down the whole system.

I'm trying to figure out which database/datastorage system might be the best option for such a system. Recently I read a lot through NoSQL solutions like Cassandra and MongoDB and it looks promising in terms of performance but comes with a flaw: it's not relational data so data have to be denormalized.

- I don't know what will be the impact of denormalizing a dynamic customer defined data model, because the customer models and inserts data first (in a relational way) and then does the queries afterwards. The denormalization has to happen automatically which leads to another problem: Can I create one table for each query, even if some queries might be similar? There might exist a high redundancy of data after a while.
- Does creating/updating tables on the fly have any impact?
- Every time the customer changes data the same data has to be changed in all tables which hold a copy of the same entity (like the name of an employee has to be changed in "team member" and also in "project task"). Are those updates costly?
- Is it possible to nest data with unlimited depth like `{"team": {"members": [{"name": "Ben"}]}}`?

There might be even better/other approaches, I'm happy for any hints.

**Adding clarification to the requirements**

**My question actually is, how can I use a NoSQL DB like Cassandra to maintain  relational data and will the solution still perform better compared to a RDBMS?**

*The customer thinks relational (because in fact, data are always relational in my opinion) no matter what DBMS is used.* And this service is not about letting the customer chose the underlying data storage. There can only be one.

A customer can define his own relational data model by using a management frontend provided by the application. The data model may be changed at any time by the customer. In RDBMS a DDL on a production system is not a good idea. On top of the data schema the customer can add named queries and use them as a data source on any web page he creates.

**An example** would be a query for News given the name "news" and in a web page it would be used like `<ul><li query="news"><h1>[news.title]</h1></li></ul>`, which would execute the query and iterate through the data and repeat the `<li>` on each iteration. That is the most simple example though.

In more complex examples if using SQL there might be extensive use of sub queries which performs bad. In NoSQL it seems there is the option to first denormalize and prepare a table with the data needed by the query and then just query that table. Any changes to involved data would lead to an update for that table. That means for every query the customer creates the system will automatically create and maintain a table and its data, so there will be a lot of data redundancy. Benchmarks state that Cassandra is fast in writing so that might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put my 2 cents in.
Talking about of ability for users having own data models is not about SaaS. 
In the pure SaaS paradigm, each user has the same functionality and data model. He could add his own objects, but not the classes of objects. 
So scaling in this paradigm is a rather obvious (though frankly, it could be not so trivial) solution. You can get cloud DB with built-in multi-tenant support (like Azure, for example), you can use Amazon's RDS and add more instances as the user amount growth, you can use sharding (for instance, a partition by users) if the database supports it, etc. 
But when we're talking about custom data model for each user is more like IaaS (infrastructure). It is some more low-level thing and you just say: "Ok, guys, you may build any data model you want, whatever". 
And I believe that if you move the responsibility for the data model creation to the user, you should also move the responsibility for database selection, as IaaS provides. So the user would say:" "Ok, I need key-value database here" and you provide him Cassandra's table for example. If he wants RDBMS, you provide him one also.
Otherwise, you have to consider not the data model itself, but also the data strategy that your customer needs. So some customer may need to have key-value storage (that needs to be backed by some noSQL DB), the other may need RDBMS. How would you know it? 
For instance, consider the entity from your example: `{"team": {"members": [{"name": "Ben"}]}}`. One user would use this model for the single type of queries something like "get the members for the team" and "add the member for the team". Another one user may need to query frequently for some stats information (average team player age, games played). 
 And these two scenarios could demand different database types: first is for key-value search, the other is RDBMS. How would you guess the database type and structure as key-value storages are modeled around queries? 
Technically, you may even try to guess the database type depending on the users' data model and queries, but you need to add some restrictions for users' creativity. Otherwise, it would be very untrivial task. 
And about scaling, as each model is unique, you need to have add database instances as users grow. Of course, you can have multiple users in the single database instance in the different schemas, and you will need to determine the users' amount per instance by experiments or performance testing. 
You may also look at the document-oriented databases, but I think that you need review your concept and make some changes.
 Maybe you have some obvious restrictions yet, but I just didn't get it from your post.

Comment: I updated my original post and hope to make it more clear. I'm completely new to NoSQL DBs and their use cases but I believe no matter what DBMS is used data are still relational (just denormalized). I'm curious how those data is managed in NoSQL databases in case there is an update on a specific relation/entity.

Comment: ie. in azure table storage world you manage consistency between denormalized but related data models in 2 ways. Strong consistency via batch operations if these denormalized entities have same partition key otherwise eventual consistency patterns leveraging azure queues and worker roles to process idompotent operations. Cosmos DB out of shelf support different consistency models so it is an evolution over table storage. Your denormalized data models should be optimized for your use cases (query, update, etc.)

Comment: In noSQL you should model your tables structure around your queries.   If you want to maintain relational data, you should maintain a relational database. Otherwise, you need to create the noSQL tables dynamically base on not the RDBMS data only, but on the queries that use these data. I don't understand your opinion about a DDL on a production system is not a good idea. You prepare dedicated schema for user and provide it. You restrict user's permissions to his tables only. Also you can do some validation of users' queries to eliminate the chance user will drop all tables.